# How do I use axios.get to get user data from Postgresql if the user data is already in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, axios, promise

I am using auth0 to sign up a user. Upon logging in, the react app will automatically obtain the user information and axios.post to the backend. It will store the id in userId and information in currUser. However, if I logout and logged in again, the whole function will not run as the data already exists in the database.

```js
const [currUser, setCurrUser] = useState([]);
const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const { user } = useAuth0();

const getUserInfo = async () => {
  const data = await axios.post(`http:localhost:8080`, {
    name: user.nickname,
    email: user.email,
  });
  setUserId(data.data[0].id);
  const personalInfo = await axios.get(
    `http:localhost:8080/${personalInfo.data[0].id}`
  );
  setCurrUser(personalInfo.data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  getUserInfo();
}, []);
```

I am not well verse with axios and promise. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what function will not run?

In case if your getUserInfo() function doesn't run, that means that your component wasn't dismounted and mounted back, so you need to add some dependency and check if user was just logged in, then fetch data about him.

If this answer doesn't helped you, pls provide more info. What that post request do, is it something like registration or what?

Comment: Hi, the whole block of getUserInfo will not run. If the user does exists, it will run the axios.post and return an axios error.  I want it to skip axios.post and go straight to axios.get for user that has signed up.

Comment: If you can make sure that user signed up, just add an exception for this case. Add some if statement around axios.post and run it only if user haven't signed up. 
Also you might want to create another endpoint to get user id in case if he signed up already, or try to find that info in user object

Comment: in order to get the id, I need to get it from my backend. But the information gotten from sign up doesnt have the id. How should I get the id then get the user information in this case?

Comment: You should follow common user flow. 
1. User appear on your app.
2. User want to sign up, in this case you fire call to endpoint that will sign him up and in response you will get his ID, then you can redirect user to some component and pass his ID there.
3. If user want to sign in, you fire call to sign in, return his ID in response and pass it to the same component, that accept ID and fire a call for details on mount. 

I'm really haven't enough information about backend you're writing and etc. to provide you more clear steps to implement what you want